# Can a PostMessage to the same window be done from multiple threads simultaneously?

Tags: c++, winapi, thread-safety, message-queue

I'm using a dispatching mechanism in my Win32 application where non-main threads can post a piece of work wrapped in an `std::function` for later execution on the main thread. This is realized by creating a hidden window from the main thread, and using its window procedure to filter out these pieces of work, and then executing them. Background threads then use a `PostMessage()` call on this window, with a custom message id (>WM_USER), while wrapping a heap-allocated `std::function` in the `LParam`.

This approach appears to be conceptually sound, but I have some reservations regarding thread-safety. MSDN makes no mention that I found, indicating whether multiple threads may or may not simultaneously post a message to the same window. Is there a definitive verdict?

Comment: Posting (or sending) messages across threads is safe.

Comment: This is a perfectly safe approach for serializing functions. To avoid leaks, just make sure you free the `function` objects after you are done using them, including if `PostMessage()` fails to post (many beginners forget that step!). Also, make sure you don't destroy the window after `PostMessage()` is called and before its message is dispatched, otherwise you will leak, so shut down all of your posting threads before destroying the window.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Good advice, but they could conceivably still be in transit on a busy system.  (And I'm not sure how best to handle that.)

Comment: @pau `PostMessage` will not return before the message has been enqueued. If you're shutting down all senders prior to destroying the receiver, there is no opportunity for a message to *"be in transit"*.

Comment: @IInspectable OK, but what happens if you destroy the receiver while there are still messages in the queue?

Comment: @pau `PeekMessage` will tell you whether the message queue is empty so that you don't have to.

Comment: @IInspectable Ah yes, silly me.  I even use that trick myself!

Comment: @PaulSanders yeah, so just shut down the senders, then pump the message queue until there are no more pending messages, then finish the rest of your shutdown

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've stayed up way too late!  I do exactly that in my own code (facepalm emoji).